# magento 2: images are not saving for configurable variations after saving through admin

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.2, product-images, aws

I have a magento (v2.2.3) website and using "thaiphan/magento2-s3" extension for uploading images to s3. Now I am facing an issue with configurable product images uploading.

For configurable variations, the image is only saving for only one size. I have attached the step by step with images. In the last step the images are hidden.

> Step1 : Selected two attributes for color and size.

[image]

> Step2 : Selected two color and two size options for variations

[image]

> Step3 : Selected 'Apply unique images by attribute to each SKU' and uploaded images for color attribute for two variations

[image]

> Step4: Two images are applied for 4 variations. ie two colors for each sizes. Everything is fine. Then clicked "Generate products"

[image]

> Step5: Generated products are successfully showing with correct images and sizes. Then I clicked "Save"

[image]

> Step6: Here is the issue. when I saved the product only two images are showing. That is the images are only available for first two sizes. That is for size 40.

[image]

> I think it is actually saving but not showing. Because when I try to edit that configurable variation, that image place holder is there.

[image]

Any idea for this issue. It is working perfectly when upload images to the same server. Only s3 has this issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? I'm facing the same problem while I'm using thai_s3 plugin

Comment: Did you find the exact reason for this issue? I have found this issue after upgrade to Magento 2.3.1